# Indexing with Numpy is inverted

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am busy reading through Python for Data Analysis by Wes Mckinney and I have encountered the following example which is slightly confusing. It pertains to passing multiple index arrays to an np array.

Given the following np.array

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31]]
```

when we execute fancy indexing on the array using the following values

```
arr[[1, 5, 7, 2], [0, 3, 1, 2]]
```

the following results

```
array([ 4, 23, 29, 10])
```

This is not really what I would expect> I understand that it should return a 1 d array of elements corresponding to each tupple of instances. The actual values it is returning confuses me.

The tuples it should be returning in my opinion would be (0,1), (5,3), (7, 1), (2, 2)

which should return [4, no such element, no such element, 10]

What exactly am I missing ?

Comment: (5, 3) and (7, 1) do exist in your array, why would you expect "no such element" for them?

Comment: I think you are mixing up the rows and the columns. The first element is the element at position `Matrix[1,0]`, which in turn means: Give me the element which is in the second row of the first column.

Comment: I would expect it to return the [x, y] value, I am very new to python so it just seems really different from conventions in other languages. so effectively it returns [y, x]

Comment: Well, I am a little surprised, that for you `M[i,j]` apparently seems to be the element at `column i  of row j`. I mean, it's really just a convention here, the developers could have defined it the other way around without any problems. However I have never seem this kind of reasoning before. For me and apparently most of the others a column vector is a one dimensional matrix, therefore the rows are the first dimension, then come the columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you index the first element in a 2D array, `arr`, you get the first row:

```
In [119]: arr = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])

In [120]: arr
Out[120]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [123]: arr[0]
Out[123]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

In NumPy-lingo, the "0-axis" therefore is associated with the rows of `arr`. Notice also the close association between `arr` and the list of lists

```
In [126]: lol = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]

In [127]: lol[0]
Out[127]: [0, 1, 2]
```

Surely, for a list of lists, it makes perfect sense that `lol[0]` should return the first *item*, which is `[0, 1, 2]`. `arr[0]` behaves the same way -- it returns what looks like a *row*.

Similarly, if you slice along the second axis you get a column.

```
In [125]: arr[:, 0]
Out[125]: array([0, 3])
```

In general, the order of the indices matches the order of the axes. The 0-axis first, the 1-axis second, and so on.

So in a 2D array, the 0-axis is associated with the rows, and the 1-axis is
associated with the columns.

This might seem backwards to you if you are thinking about the elements of the array being arranged along x and y axes. In geometry, the x-axis is usually pointing to the right, and the y-axis is vertical. So in geometry the coordinate (x, y) gives the horizontal index first, then the vertical index.

When indexing arrays, the association is reversed for the reason shown above.

Comment: The example and the maths analogy is very good.  Thanks